# Why do I get a type mismatch error comparing two strings

Tags: ms-access, vba

Into a macro I inserted for if criteria the following condition:

```
[Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].[Report]![Field]<>"Empty"
```

Note That [Field] is set to short text and default value ="Empty"

The rezult is that when I run the macro I get the type mismatch error.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experince with reports in VBA, but could you be missing a property of `[Field]`? Maybe `[Field].Value` or `[Field].Text`

Comment: Default Acces is .Value. Tried the .text thow. Didn't work! Same error.

Comment: The macro stops at first row (if) when it wants to setlocalvar _*L0_ value to the true/false response variable. Seems like the _*L0_ needs one type of variable and (this is the odd part) if() / strcomp() doesn't supplies it (although it should).

Comment: I bypassed the problem by using a form instead of a report. It seems that the report field gives a wrong form of short text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `StrComp()` function?
[Here's the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/strcomp-function)

Comment: I tried. Same error (macro single step error 13 at setlocalvar: _*L0_;...

Comment: I bypassed the problem by using a form instead of a report. It seems that the report field gives a wrong form of short text.